# Native mosquito mqtt docker container rejects connections

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto

I have started mosquito mqtt docker server with command:

```
C:\Users\g> docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 eclipse-mosquitto

1686127493: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1686127493: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1686127493: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1686127493: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1686127493: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
1686127493: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1686127493: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1686127493: Error: Address not available
1686127493: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
```

All clients that is trying to connect are dropped? Why?

This is `mosquitto-no-auth.conf` file I found in image content:

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

Looks anonymous are allowed. What else might be wrong?

Comment: `/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf` != `mosquitto-no-auth.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, the default configuration file is at `/mosquitto/conf/mosquitto.conf` not the `/mosquitto-no-auth.conf`.

If you want to run with the `mosquitto-no-auth.conf` file then the command line should be:

```
docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 eclipse-mosquitto mosquitto -c /mosquitto-no-auth.conf
```

Comment: Is it possible to run -c /mosquitto-no-auth.conf option from Docker Desktop?

Comment: I don't run docker desktop, but expect it should be possible to pass a command and arguments